# Comparing and combining a List of similar strings

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of strings that I have to run through multiple times to try to reduce duplicates.

```
List <string> EventsList = BuildList.Distinct().ToList();
```

This removes *exact* copies but occasionally there will be a duplicate event message that contains different variations on the exact same event.

For instance:

> Error code [123]: Failure in the [X] directory.
>
> Error code [123]: Failure in the [Y] directory.

The intent being that I can compare these strings again and come up with the output:

> Error code [123]: Failure in the [X, Y] directory.

Since the varying input is always in brackets I created the

```
string pattern = @"\[([^\]]+)";
RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled;
Regex ConsolidatorRegex = new Regex(pattern, options);
BuildList = EventsList;
foreach (string singleEvent in BuildList)
{
    ConsolidatorRegex.Replace(singleEvent, "");
}
```

Thinking that I could then compare the strings and remove the duplicates again.

But now I'm stuck. I want to preserve the original order of the chronological events as much as possible but I can't figure the best way to go about this. Running `BuildList.Distinct().ToList();` again doesn't help me capture the (often multiple) removed Matches so I can add them back in.

I thought I could run a loop that does a `String.Equals` method and put all the hits into a dictionary then compare the dictionary to the `EventsList`, but I couldn't get the index of the loop in order to create dictionary key.

Is there a better way to go about this that I'm missing?

Comment: Approximately how many different kinds of error codes are there?

Comment: @Rodrick Around 300 I think? Not everything throws an error code, however, as some things are simply events like "Task started on [server name]." I just wanted to provide an example with multiple Regex matches per string.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your won comparer as mentioned [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436(v=vs.110).aspx).

From the docs:

> To compare a custom data type, you need to implement this interface
>   and provide your own GetHashCode and Equals methods for the type.

See [the docs for that one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `GroupBy` function to group you strings.

```
var eventListGrouping = BuildList.GroupBy(eventString => ConsolidatorRegex.Replace(eventString, ""));
```

Then you can iterate over the groups:

```
foreach(var variation in eventListGrouping) 
{
    // Use variation.Key to find your 'template string'
    // Iterate over variation to find all the string you want to combine
    // You can reuse you regex to extract the values you want to combine
    // Pay attention to adhere to the correct regex match count.
}
```

For more info on the `IGrouping` interface, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var memo = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

var event_list = new List<string> 
    { 
        "Error code [123]: Failure in the [X] directory.",
        "Error code [123]: Failure in the [Y] directory.",
        "Error code [456]: Failure in the [Y] service.",
    };

var pattern = new Regex(@"(code\s\[(?'code'\d+)\]).*\[(?'message'.*)\]");

foreach(var item in event_list)
{       

    var match = pattern.Match(item);
    var code = Int32.Parse(match.Groups["code"].Value);
    var msg = match.Groups["message"].Value;

    var messages = default(List<string>);

    if(!memo.TryGetValue(code, out messages))
        memo.Add(code, messages = new List<string>());

    messages.Add(msg);
}

var directory_errors = from x in memo where x.Key == 123 select x;

foreach(var error in directory_errors)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Error code [{0}]: Failure in the [{1}] directory", error.Key, string.Join(",", from err in error.Value select "'" + err + "'")));
```

The idea is that we have we use a dictionary of type `Dictionary<int, List<string>>` where the key is the error code (assumed to be an `int`) and the value is a `List<string>`.

For each event, we use a regex to extract the code and the message, we then check the dictionary to see if there is already a list of messages associated with that code, if so we simply add to the list, but if not, then we create the list and add it to the dictionary (using the error code as the key), and then we add to the list.

[**Rextester Demo**](http://rextester.com/IYGFS41846).